# How can I clean cooking oil out of plug sockets?

Tags: electrical, fire-hazard, cord-and-plug

[image]I spilled a lot of uncooked oil onto the 4 power sockets plugged into my extension lead. the oil also got on the extension lead-should i unplug the sockets and stop using them. I’m really anxious it might explode or cause a fire

Comment: Flush the entire thing out with soapy water. Shake it out well. Let it dry for 24 hours.

Comment: Do unplug it first before washing.

Comment: Otherwise, it's a £13 part. Replace it.

Comment: Chinesium check says it's a legit product sold at Wickes.

Answer (score 4):

You should certainly stop using it while it has oil in it.

Once it's unplugged, you could flush it with soapy water, then clean water, shake out as much as possible and let it dry for at least 24 hours. That's not entirely reliable, though.

Or you might be able to take it apart to clean it, but then you have to put it all back together and unless you *really* know what you're doing, that's even less recommended. [Read: don't do that.]

**It's cheap. Replace it.**